# jquery ui dialog box not opening

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to implement a jquery ui dialog box in my web app but it doesnt seem to work at all. I am using PHP.

I have  a **PHP** code which defines the  for dialog and a button which on clicked will open the dialog.

```
    <div id="dialog">This should show up </div> 
<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button>
```

I have a separate JS file and inside the ready function, I have the following code

```
$("#dialog").dialog({autoOpen:false}); 


$("#opener").click(function()
{
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});
```

On clicking the button, the dialog doesnt seem to open up. I am using

- jquery V1.7.1
- jquery UI V 1.8.20

Can anyone help me with why it wouldn't work.

Also, I tried setting autoOpen to true and the dialog seems to work fine on page loading but not when clicked.

Thanks for ur help

Comment: Try returning false from within the click function? Maybe the default "button" click functionality is interfering?

Comment: Do you have any errors in your console log? Press F12, go to the 'console' tab, and try clicking the button.

Comment: No errors, warnings, or logs. But I just tried $("#dialog").dialog(open); (no quotes for open and seemed to work. Did I get the syntax wrong?

Comment: The syntax looked right to me, but as another user suggested try putting return false; at the end of the callback to prevent the button from performing any default action that would override it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the click code is run after the page has loaded, or it may not be able to find it and attach. I wrapped your JS code in jQuery's [.ready()](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) to be sure.

The following example should do as you ask. If you want further assistance, I suggest you post a URL that we can look at and debug.

```
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    //Wait until the document is ready to be processed.
    jQuery(document).ready(function()
    {
        //Init your dialog box.
        $("#dialog").dialog({autoOpen:false}); 

        //Attach you click handler to the button.
        $("#opener").click(function(event)
        {
            //Stop any default actions on the button.
            event.preventDefault();
            //Open your dialog.
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
        });
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="dialog">This should show up </div> 
<button id="opener">Open Dialog</button> 

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
$("#opener").on('click', function(){
    $("#dialog").dialog("open");
});​
```

Here is working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x3Wjj/)

Comment: I just checked the documentation, and you are right, it is not deprecated. However i am certain that i read somewhere suggesting to use _on_ instead of _click_ although it is shorthand of _on_. Thanks for reminding though.

Comment: Click is not deprecated; live() is. Look at the [API](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

Comment: Yes that was what i remembered. Thanks. I deleted the wrong information in my post. For reference, here is what i deleted: "The _click_ is deprecated, use _on_ instead."